# ReadDirectoryChangesW not working with delete

Tags: winapi, filesystemwatcher, readdirectorychangesw

im using winapi for filewatching in my windows PC. i used the basic method of implementing the filewatcher using CreateFile, ReadDirectoryChangesW  with certain filters 
 FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME |  FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE

im observe the directory while creating files inside the folder(directory)
the filewatcher works properly on creation of file, rename, copy everything except delete . shift delete is working properly on the file.

my code

```
 QString newDirName;
         char buf[2048];
         DWORD nRet;
         BOOL result=TRUE;
         char filename[MAX_PATH];

         //path = L"K:/Demo/bb";

         wchar_t* arr = (wchar_t*)path;
         printf("\nThe file  directory: [%s] \n", path);
         qDebug() << "WatchDirectory Watcher Path " << QString::fromWCharArray(arr);
         DirInfo[0].hDir = CreateFile (path, GENERIC_READ|FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
                                       FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                                       NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
                                       NULL);

         if(DirInfo[0].hDir == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
         {
             qDebug() << "Can not open";
             return;
         }

         lstrcpy( DirInfo[0].lpszDirName, path);
         OVERLAPPED PollingOverlap;

         FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION pNotify[1024];
         int offset;
         PollingOverlap.OffsetHigh = 0;
         PollingOverlap.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL,TRUE,FALSE,NULL);



         while(result)
         {
             result = ReadDirectoryChangesW(
                        DirInfo[0].hDir,// handle to the directory to be watched
                        (LPVOID)&pNotify,// pointer to the buffer to receive the read results
                        sizeof(pNotify),// length of lpBuffer
                        1,// flag for monitoring directory or directory tree
                        FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME |  FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE  ,
                      &nRet,// number of bytes returned
                      &PollingOverlap,// pointer to structure needed for overlapped I/O
                      NULL);

             WaitForSingleObject(PollingOverlap.hEvent,INFINITE);
//             if(result)
//             {
             offset = 0;
             int rename = 0;
             char oldName[260];
             char newName[260];

             do
             {
                 //pNotify = (FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION*)((char*)buf + offset);
                 strcpy(filename, "");
                 int filenamelen = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, pNotify[offset].FileName, pNotify[offset].FileNameLength/2, filename, sizeof(filename), NULL, NULL);
                 //filename[pNotify->FileNameLength/2] = ' ';

                 switch(pNotify[offset].Action)
                 {
                     case FILE_ACTION_ADDED:
                      qDebug() << "The FILE_ACTION_ADDED***********" << QString(filename).left(filenamelen);
                      emit onFileCopy(QString(filename).left(filenamelen));
                          break;
                     case FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED:
                        qDebug() << "The FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED" << QString(filename).left(filenamelen);

                         break;
                     case FILE_ACTION_REMOVED:
                         qDebug() << "The FILE_ACTION_REMOVED" << QString(filename).left(filenamelen);
                         emit onFileRemove(QString(filename).left(filenamelen));
                     break;
                     case FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_OLD_NAME:
                     qDebug() << "The FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_OLD_NAME" << QString(filename).left(filenamelen);
                         break;
                     case FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_NEW_NAME:
                      newDirName = QString(filename).left(filenamelen);
                      qDebug() << "The FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_NEW_NAME" << newDirName;
                        emit onDirRename(newDirName);
                         break;
                     default:
                         printf("\nDefault error.\n");
                         break;
                  }

                 //qDebug() << "pNotify->NextEntryOffset" << pNotify[offset].NextEntryOffset <<" offset "<< offset << nRet ;
                 offset += pNotify[offset].NextEntryOffset;
              }while(pNotify[offset].NextEntryOffset); //(offset != 0)
             ResetEvent(PollingOverlap.hEvent);
            }

          CloseHandle( DirInfo[0].hDir );
```

i not able to get the notification when normal delete is done on the files inside the watched directory.

Comment: You are using a manually reset event in your `OVERLAPPED` structure. Are you resetting it after each `WaitForSingleObject()`? Just to be sure you can try removing `PollingOverlap` and try with non-overlapping IO.

Comment: Looks like you just quit without trying it, not clear why.  You need to pay attention to FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION.Action, it will be FILE_ACTION_REMOVED when a file was deleted.  Note that the buffer size you pass to ReadDirectoryChangesW() is wrong, it needs to be bytes.

Comment: thanks rodigo and hans passant for the reply .i apologise for my bad way in explaining my question.  i have updated my complete implemention . you can see im using resetEvent on the pollingOverlap event.case FILE_ACTION_REMOVED: is called only on the Sift+delete option.

Comment: i updated my post with my complete implementation.

Comment: Trying to channel what "Sift + delete" might mean: when you delete a file with Explorer then it doesn't get deleted, it gets *moved* to the recycle bin.   You'll get the FILE_ACTION_RENAMED notifications.

Comment: No Hans im not getting any notification when i move it to recycle bin. but it happens when i do Cut/paste